# The Character Class in Java

Tags: java, character

Here is a short program that counts the letters of any given word entered by the user. 
I'm trying to figure out what the following lines actually do in this program:

counts[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++; // I don't understand what the - 'a' is doing

System.out.println((char)('a' + i) // I don't get what the 'a' + i actually does.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Listing9_3 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Create a scanner
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a word to find out the occurences of each letter: ");
            String s = input.nextLine();

            //Invoke the count Letters Method to count each letter
            int[] counts = countLetters(s.toLowerCase());

            //Display results
            for(int i = 0; i< counts.length; i++){
                if(counts[i] != 0)
                    System.out.println((char)('a' + i) + " appears " + 
                counts[i] + ((counts[i] == 1)? " time" : " times"));
    ***//I don't understand what the 'a' + i is doing
            }
        }
        public static int[] countLetters(String s) {
            int[] counts = new int [26]; // 26 letters in the alphabet

            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))
                    counts[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;   
  ***// I don't understand what the - 'a' is doin
            }
            return counts;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `char` is actually an unsigned 16-bit integer.  When you add `a`, you are adding the ASCII value for `a` when you subtract `a` you are subtracting the same value, but without having to look up which value this is.

Comment: (The Unicode value, which happens to be numerically equal to the ASCII value, since ASCII is a subset of Unicode.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters are a kind of integer in Java; the integer is a number associated with the character on the Unicode chart.  Thus, `'a'` is actually the integer 97; `'b'` is 98, and so on in sequence up through `'z'`.  So `s.charAt(i)` returns a character; assuming that it is a lower-case letter in the English alphabet, subtracting `'a'` from it gives the result 0 for `'a'`, 1 for `'b'`, 2 for `'c'`, and so on.

You can see the first 4096 characters of the Unicode chart at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF (and there will be references to other pages of the chart as well).  You'll see `'a'` there as U+0061 (which is hex, = 97 decimal).

Answer (score 3):

Because you want your array to contains only the count of each letter from `'a'` to `'z'`.

So to index correctly each count of the letter within the array you would need a mapping `letter -> index` with `'a' -> 0`, `'b' -> 1` to `'z' -> 25`.

Each character is represented by a integer value on 16 bits (so from 0 to 65,535). You're only interested from the letters `'a'` to `'z'`, which have respectively the values 97 and 122.

How would you get the mapping?

This can be done using the trick `s.charAt(i) - 'a'`.

This will ensure that the value returned by this operation is between 0 and 25 because you know that `s.charAt(i)` will return a character between `'a'` and `'z'` (you're converting the input of the user in lower case and using `Character.isLetter`)

Hence you got the desired mapping to count the occurences of each letter in the word.

On the other hand, `(char)('a' + i)` does the reverse operation. `i` varies from 0 to 25 and you respectively got the letters from `'a'` to `'z'`. You just need to cast the result of the addition to `char` otherwise you would see its unicode value be printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
counts[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++; // I don't understand what the - 'a' is doing 
assume charAT(i) is 'z'
now z-a will be equal to 25 (subtract the unicode / ASCII values).
so counts[25]=counts[25]+1;  // just keeps track of count of each character
```